# Iterating a list in stages in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration

I've been working with time-series data in Python recently, and have run into a number of scenarios where I need to iterate over a list of data values, and do different things at different points in the iteration, depending on the data leading up to it. The scenarios are all solveable with single-pass iterations, and it's not hard to figure out how to write the code that does it, but every time it feels like I'm overcomplicating it and writing more code than necessary. It feels like there should be a simpler, more pythonic way.

A simplified typical example would be something like this:

```
def find_above_threshold_for_n(readings, upper, n)
  segments = [] # A list-of-lists of contiguous readings above `upper`
  current = None
  for value in readings:
    if value < upper:
       # 1. Skip ahead to first threshold-crossing value.
       current = None
    else:
      if current is None:
        current = []
        count = 0
      current.append(value)
      count += 1
      # 2. Keep iterating until we find n above threshold
      if count >= n:
         # 3. If we find enough readings, keep this segment. We'll continue adding to it until we dip below threshold again.
         segments.append(current)
  return segments
```

That concept works, but it feels like it should be achievable in fewer lines of code, and with a structure that better maps my mental model.

As you can see, there are three basic stages as we loop through the list -- skip to the first relevant value, carry on collecting values until n, and continue collecting values until next unwanted value, then rinse and repeat. Each stage carries on from where the previous left off. It feels like there should be a simple idiom to achieve this, because the above code doesn't really make those stages obvious.

It's not always the same stages or threshold algorithm (eg some data I'm processing is locations and it's about how far a tracking device as moved), but there's regularly a family resemblance of moving through a list in stages.

I'm looking for something like:

```
segments = []
while readings:
  while next(readings) < upper:
     continue
  segment = []
  reading = next(readings)
  while reading >= upper:
    segment.append(reading)
    reading = next(readings)
  if len(segment) >= n:
    segments.append(segment)
```

Unfortunately, manually looping over iterators in Python isn't that pretty, because you have to have 3 extra lines of try/except to detect the StopIteration whenever you call next(). And even without that, the above "improved" code isn't dramatically simpler, although it does map my mental model a bit closer.

I'm trying to avoid explicit indices (i.e. looping over the length of the list) because they're so prone to off-by-one and accidental overrun errors, and they rarely result in cleaner code.

Is there a cleaner way to iterate over a list in stages, at each stage picking up where the last stage left off? Or, is there an outright better way to go about solving this kind of problem?

Comment: Do you have example data?

Comment: Further simplification of my mental model of this problem, fwiw: ``` while readings: skip = [r for r in readings while r < upper]; segment = [r for r in readings while r >= upper]; if len(segment) >= n: segments.append(segment) ```

Comment: Example data for this simplified scenario would just be a list of numbers, eg `data = [1,7,9,11,10,9,8,6,7,8,9,1,2,5,8,3]`. Example results would be `find_above_threshold_for_n(data, 7, 3) -> [[7,9,11,10,9,8], [7,8,9]]`

Answer (score 2):

With `itertools.groupby` it can become a bit shorter:

```
import itertools


def find_above_threshold_for_n(readings, upper, n):
    segments = []

    for valid, group in itertools.groupby(readings, lambda v: v >= upper):
        if not valid: continue

        group = list(group)
        if len(group) < n:
            continue

        segments.append(group)

    return segments


data = [1,7,9,11,10,9,8,6,7,8,9,1,2,5,8,3]
print(find_above_threshold_for_n(data, 7, 3))
```

Even shorter but maybe less readable:

```
from itertools import groupby


def find_above_threshold_for_n(readings, upper, n):
    segments = [list(group) for valid, group in
            groupby(readings, lambda v: v >= upper) if valid]

    return list(filter(lambda g: len(g) >= n, segments))
```

Comment: Very nice solution! But you could return `list(...)` directly, that would make it even shorter.

Comment: @AlexR Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Instead of `segments = list(filter(lambda g: len(g) >= n, segments))` you could just write `return list(filter(lambda g: len(g) >= n, segments))`. No need for the extra assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you could create all segments and then filter for the segments you are looking for:

```
def find_above_threshold_for_n(readings, upper, n):
    segments = [[]]
    for reading in readings:
        if reading >= upper:
            # append to the last segment
            segments[-1].append(reading)
        elif segments[-1]:
            # add a new segment if the last segment is not empty
            segments.append([])
    # only return segments with length >= n
    return list(filter(lambda l: len(l) >= n, segments))
```

Calling:

```
data = [1, 7, 9, 11, 10, 9, 8, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 5, 8, 3]
print(find_above_threshold_for_n(data, 7, 3))
```

generates the output: `[[7, 9, 11, 10, 9, 8], [7, 8, 9]]`